# Struggling adding this mysql foreign key.

Tags: mysql

So I'm having a bit of an issue here and I cant seem to solve the problem. I'm creating a new table `Assessment_Subsection_To_Group` and then I need to add a column and foreign key to `Assessment_Subsection` that will create a link between them.

The code that I have so far is shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Assessment_Subsection_To_Group` (
    `assessment_subsection_to_group_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `time_created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `time_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `person_id_created` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `person_id_modified` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`assessment_subsection_to_group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Assessment_Subsection`
ADD COLUMN `assessment_subsection_to_group_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL FIRST,
ADD FOREIGN KEY `assessment_subsection_to_group_id_ibfk` (`assessment_subsection_to_group_id`) REFERENCES `Assessment_Subsection_To_Group` (`assessment_subsection_to_group_id`);
```

The table creates as expected the problem comes when I try to alter `Assessment_Subsection` to try and add the constraint. I get this error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`at`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-47f_48'>, CONSTRAINT `assessment_subsection_to_group_id_ibfk` FOREIGN KEY (`assessment_subsection_to_group_id`) REFERENCES `Assessment_Subsection_)
```

I then checked `show engine innodb status;` which gave me this message. I can't make head of tales of it. The sql looks right to me but I'm obviously missing something.

```
ALTER TABLE `Assessment_Subsection` ADD COLUMN `assessment_subsection_to_group_id` INT (11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL FIRST, ADD CONSTRAINT `assessment_subsec
Foreign key constraint fails for table `at`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-47f_48'>:
,CONSTRAINT `assessment_subsection_to_group_id_ibfk` FOREIGN KEY (`assessment_subsection_to_group_id`) REFERENCES `Assessment_Subsection_To_Group` (`
Trying to add in child table, in index `assessment_subsection_to_group_id_ibfk` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000000b; asc     ;;

But in parent table `at`.`Assessment_Subsection_To_Group`, in index `PRIMARY`,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 696e66696d756d00; asc infimum ;;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so i think I solved this.

I created the `Assessment_Subsection_To_Group` table which is empty.

My `Assessment_Subsection` table already has a lot of data in it. When I added the new column in, it populated that column with the default value of `0`. So when I try to add the foreign key to `Assessment_Subsection` it sees the `0` value in the columns and sees nothing to reference that to in the `Assessment_Subsection_To_Group` table and spits its' dummy out.

So I solved the problem by adding in a record to the `Assessment_Subsection_To_Group` and then updating the column with `0`'s in it to match the id of the record I just added to `Assessment_Subsection_To_Group` and tried to add the foreign key again and it worked a treat.

There surely has to be a simpler way of doing this though?

Answer (score 0):

Split the alter into two stages. Add the column in one, then add the foreign key in another. The column doesn't exist until after the alter completes, but you're already trying to do things with it from within the statement that creates it.

e.g. you're trying to butter your bread while it's still in the mixer, before it's even baked.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation and the metaphor ;), I tried your suggestion but it's still giving me the error.

Comment: is it just me, or is the field you're trying to add already in the table, and you're trying to FK it to itself? Please tell me it's just a Friday thing and I need to have a good sleep-in saturday morning?

Comment: Errm I don't think thats what I'm doing. Would it cause problems if the table I'm trying to add the foreign key to is populated with 0?

Comment: Yes. if there's records in there that wouldn't have a matching foreign record, the alter will fail. You'd have to disable FK checks before doing the alter, and then you'd still have orphaned records.

Comment: That was the problem all along, I'll remember that for next time. Thanks for your help, If you want to update your answer I'll accept it.